# Trigonometric Integration: Using the half-angle formula?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'll preface my question by saying this is my first ever post. I've been lurking around and answering a couple logic questions here and there, but since I have an intractable calculus question I figure it's time to break the ice.

I've been stumped on a definite trigonometric integration for a couple days. In particular, I'm having a tough time getting the integrand in an appropriate form so I can proceed.

I'm thinking this might happen with the half-angle formula, but I've been unable to set it up. Any nudge in the right direction (I'm not looking for an answer), would be very appreciated.

Suppose I were to evaluate:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/6}6\sqrt{1-cos\,6x}\,dx$$

My strategy thus far is to get $sin^26x$ within the square root and cancel them out in order to have $sin6x$.

However, to do so I'm thinking I will need to use a Pythagorean identity, or a half-angle formula. The one standing out to me as a great candidate is:

$$sin^2x = \frac{1-cos\,2x}{2}$$

I'm kicking things off by moving the constant outside of the integrand:

$$6\int_{0}^{\pi/6}\sqrt{1-cos\,6x}\,dx$$

Yet I can't seem to figure out a possible means of dividing $1-cos\,6x$ by 2 (due to the square root). If this is a decent strategy, what might be my first step or two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep kicking in and out (and balancing) constants and applying your candidate formula:

$$6\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/6}\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\,6x}{2}}\,dx = 6\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/6}|\sin 3x|\,dx$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was exactly the bump I needed to get started. I just successfully worked through the rest of the integration.